# Laravel 5.7 on Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, laravel-5, azure-web-app-service

I have Laravel installed on Microsoft Azure server, and all of the sudden the website stopped working with the log message below

```
    production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]  (SQL: select * from `menus` where exists (select * from `menu_translations` where `menus`.`id` = `menu_translations`.`menu_id` and `columns` = 0)) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]  (SQL: select * from `menus` where exists (select * from `menu_translations` where `menus`.`id` = `menu_translations`.`menu_id` and `columns` = 0)) at D:\\home\\site\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:664, Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]  at D:\\home\\site\\vendor\\doctrine\\dbal\\lib\\Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOConnection.php:31, PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]  at D:\\home\\site\\vendor\\doctrine\\dbal\\lib\\Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOConnection.php:27, PDOException(code: 0): PDO::__construct(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed at D:\\home\\site\\vendor\\doctrine\\dbal\\lib\\Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOConnection.php:27)
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There was an intermittent issue with Azure SQL resources.

Customers may experience difficulties connecting to Azure SQL and database services, including Azure SQL Database, Azure Database for PostgreSQL, Azure Database for MySQL, Azure Database for MariaDB, Azure Cosmos DB, and SQL Data Warehouse. Some customers may also experience intermittent timeouts or error messages when performing service management operations.

Subscription Admins have been notified about the same.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I solved the issue by pointing opennssl to the cacert.pem in user.ini and restarted. Now it is stable.